# Mongoose - $text search breaks inside $or condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to search a document using Mongoose, if the user sends some text in their request I then make an OR condition on the query to say 'see if this text matches fields X or Y', in plain english:

```
var query = {
        date: { $gte: start_date, $lt: end_date},
        author: req._user._id,
        link: { $eq: link},
    };
```

The above fields will always be searched against. I then check for text being present, if it is I want to search against the documents $text index to see if that matches the search text OR I want to see if the search text is contained in the documents 'tags' array. This OR condition throws an error with the $text index.

```
if (searchText.length) {

        query["$or"] = [
            {
                "$text": { "$search": searchText}
            },
            {
                "tags": { "$in": [searchText]}
            }
        ];
    }
```

I get mongodb errors such as 'MongoError: error processing query' and 'No query solutions'.

I've narrowed it down to the $text index. If I replace the $text index field in the OR condition and replace it with a simple field match, all works fine:

```
query["$or"] = [
            {
                "title":  "Foo" // Replaced $text search with this and it works.
            },
            {
                "tags": { "$in": [searchText]}
            }
        ];
```

Am I doing something Mongoose doesn't allow, or that MongoDB doesn't allow?

Comment: I have the same problem too. Still I can't find the solution.